# php - extract custom tr from html string by element tag name

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I want to extract some parts of a html source , this is the section it need :

```
<tr data-market-row="price_eur" data-title="" class="pointer " onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; window.location='profile/price_eur'" data-price="321,110" data-url="">
```

I need to extract the section that has data-market-row="price_eur" , I tried this code but it doesn't work :

```
$html = str_get_html($str);
foreach ($html->find('tr.data-market-row') as $e)
$a = $e->outertext;
```

how can I take out this tr row with this tag name

```
data-market-row="price_eur"
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using Simple HTML DOM parser and you have a problem with your selector.  Try this:

```
$html = str_get_html($str);
foreach ($html->find('tr[data-market-row]') as $e) {
    echo "<pre>TAG: "; print_r($e->tag); echo "</pre>";
    echo "<pre>PRICE: "; print_r($e->getAttribute('data-price')); echo "</pre>";
    echo "<pre>OUTER: "; print_r($e->outertext); echo "</pre>";
    echo "<pre>INNER: "; print_r($e->innertext); echo "</pre>";
    echo "<pre>PLAIN: "; print_r($e->plaintext); echo "</pre>";
    echo "ELEMENT: <pre>"; echo "<pre>"; print_r($e); echo "</pre>"; echo "</pre>"; exit;
}
```

Here I've output various properties of $e, and it doesn't appear that the element has inner, outer or plain text.  You can access the price attribute.  I have just printed the variables so you can see them.  If you want to get the price into a variable, use this:

```
$price = $e->getAttribute('data-price');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to extract the **tr** tags with the attribute **data-market-row="price_eur"**:

```
$txt = '<tr data-market-row="price_eur" data-title="" class="pointer " onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; window.location=\'profile/price_eur\'" data-price="321,110" data-url="">' .
       '<tr some-other stuff here>' .
       '<tr data-market-row="price_eur">' .

$pattern = '/<tr [^>]*data-market-row="price_eur"[^>]*>/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $txt, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);

/*  Here is the output:
Array
(
    [0] => <tr data-market-row="price_eur" data-title="" class="pointer " onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; window.location='profile/price_eur'" data-price="321,110" data-url="">
    [1] => <tr data-market-row="price_eur">
)
*/
```

The example fails, if you don't want to match javascript strings or html comments (or the like) containing a similar table row.